# Pandas: Reading big CSV with variable timestamp

Tags: pandas, variables, timestamp

I have a log file per day which is placed in my LAN on a http server that grows to about 3MB per day.
Every 15 seconds new values are written to that file. It has a timestamp column. There are many other columns which are not needed for me, so I only need about 5 of the columns.
Pandas should "monitor" that file by reading only records which are new. Let's say last execution was 2018-02-05 00:00:04.467 then this should be the filter for next runtime (>2018-02-05 00:00:04.467) and in the end of this runtime the last timestamp read should be filter for next and so on...
I'm new to pandas and haven't found any similar thread for this.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the CSV would be written line by line, so instead of reading the whole file and filtering, you could accumulate the number of rows in the file in a variable `rows` and for the next run, use `read_csv` passing in the optional argument [`skiprows`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) with value `range(1, rows + 1)` to skip the first rows in the file, and then incrementing `rows += len(df)`

If `data.csv` is

```
a,b,c
1,2,3
4,5,6
7,8,9
3,2,1
6,5,4
```

and `rows = 2` (i.e., the last time the file was read it had 2 rows) then

```
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv", usecols=["a", "c"], skiprows=range(1, rows + 1))
```

would be the dataframe

```
   a  c
0  7  9
1  3  1
2  6  4
```

and you would increment `rows`

```
rows += len(df) # rows now equals 5, so 5 rows would be skipped in the next run
```